# Why can't I declare a method in generics this way?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I started learning TS, and I can't understand what is wrong with this class method:

```
class HoldAnything<T> {
  data: T

  add(a: T): T {
    return this.data + a
  }
}
```

VS code underlines `return this.data + a`, and it says:

```
Operator + cannot be applied to types T and T
```

I can't understand why it's showing me this error.
Probably, it was answered somewhere already, however, I can't find it. I'd appreciate if someone could explain what is wrong with the method or point me to the answer.

Comment: Cause there is absolutely no guarantee, that your `T` supports addition? Try writing `[] + []`, TS will also complain - and it would additionally not result in the same type as both inputs.

Comment: @ASDFGerte oh I see now the problem. So, how do I define a method like this ? Let's say it will be used with data types that support addition.

Comment: you can tell to T that it extends the datatypes that you support. for example: `class HoldAnything<T extends string> {` <-- scratch that, won't work this way.